# what am i doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I keeping getting this error during table creation: Order is not valid at this position expecting an identifier. I looked it up on the Web but I can't figure out how to fix this. What does the error mean, and how do i fix it?

```
CREATE TABLE CARD
(
 card_no varchar(30) primary key,
 Name_on_Card varchar(50),
 Card_limit numeric(10,2),
 EXP_date date 
);

CREATE table PURCHASE
(
 Ref_no varchar(30) primary key,
 Purchase_Date date,
 Purchase_Amount numeric(8,2),
 Card_No varchar(30), FOREIGN key references Card(card_No)
);
create table Bill
(
  Bill_No varchar(30),
  Amount_Due numeric(10,2),
  Due_Date date,
  Patment_Date date,
  Ref_No varchar(30) foreign key references Purchase(Ref_No)
);
create table Redemption
(
  Tran_Code varchar(30) primary key,
  Tran_Date date,
  Merchandise varchar(100)
);
create table Premium_Card
(
  Card_No varchar(30) foreign key references Card(Card_No),
  Tran_Code varchar(30) foreign key references Redemption(Tran_Code),
  Bonus_Points int,
  Bonus_Exp_Date date
);
```

Answer (score 0):

FOREIGN KEY definition:

1. is separate clause
2. needs in referencing expression

```sql
CREATE TABLE CARD
(
 card_no varchar(30) primary key,
 Name_on_Card varchar(50),
 Card_limit numeric(10,2),
 EXP_date date 
);

CREATE table PURCHASE
(
 Ref_no varchar(30) primary key,
 Purchase_Date date,
 Purchase_Amount numeric(8,2),
 Card_No varchar(30), 
 FOREIGN key (Card_No) references Card(card_No)
);
create table Bill
(
  Bill_No varchar(30),
  Amount_Due numeric(10,2),
  Due_Date date,
  Patment_Date date,
  Ref_No varchar(30),
  foreign key (Ref_No) references Purchase(Ref_no)
);
create table Redemption
(
  Tran_Code varchar(30) primary key,
  Tran_Date date,
  Merchandise varchar(100)
);
create table Premium_Card
(
  Card_No varchar(30),
  foreign key (Card_No) references Card(Card_No),
  Tran_Code varchar(30),
  foreign key (Tran_Code) references Redemption(Tran_Code),
  Bonus_Points int,
  Bonus_Exp_Date date
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/wPudTcqH